# Starship vs submarine hull

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, high-pressure-environment

Just out of curiosity, which can endure higher internal pressure - submarine hull or starship fuel tank? Any comparative figures in bars? I guess, in vaccum explosion can happen and under the deep sea, the risk of implosion looms.

Comment: Not duplicates because they refer to (at least in part) *external overpressure*, but for some background refer to [Is the pressurization of propellant tanks necessary for structural integrity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18332/12102) and a little bit of [Final conclusion/description of the cause of the SpaceX Sept. 1, 2016 anomaly? What's a “buckle”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19661)

Comment: Subs are made to withstand crush loads and spacecraft, burst loads. Spacecraft hull design is, to put it mildly, more weight sensitive than that of subs. I can hardly conceive of a more apples/oranges comparison.

Comment: 1 atm of internal pressures seems trivial for a vessel that can handle tens of atms of external pressure.

Comment: More related: [Do spacecraft have similar structural integrity requirements as submarines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/do-spacecraft-have-similar-structural-integrity-requirements-as-submarines) [Repurposing a nuclear submarine for space travel](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27367/repurposing-a-nuclear-submarine-for-space-travel)

Comment: @OrganicMarble While that is true, once you've bolted together a couple half-meter-thick hulls with a zillion cross-braces, overpressuring the interior (other than the hatches themselves) is not likely to do much.

Comment: This all reminds me of that unfortunate era in *Astounding Science Fiction's* history when John Campbell wanted to bolt Dean Drives into submarines to win the race to the moon and Mars.  https://i.pinimg.com/originals/54/a9/53/54a9533dfcb406638e8492208b9034fb.jpg